# MySQL statement convert to pretty Rails AR Statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, performance

I have a MySQL statement that took me all night to come up with.  I'm wondering if this thing can be converted from a direct call to something pretty like Object.find(:conditions)

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("
    SELECT *, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM scores AS temp2 
      WHERE temp2.score > scores.score 
      ORDER BY score DESC) + 1 AS rank 
    FROM scores 
    WHERE user_id=%s 
    ORDER BY score DESC" 
    % user_id).fetch_hash
```

This statement is part of a high score website built for a Android game.  It gets the top high score and has a subquery that gives it the rank as well.

Can this be made into something nicer?  Also, is this the most efficient method of going about this?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: Can you describe in more details what you want to do and how your schema fits together?  It's hard to reverse engineer the sql and your description is a bit vague.

Comment: He's trying to figure out how many scores are higher than the score of a given user.... I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
user = Score.find_by_user_id(id)
rank = Score.count(:conditions => ['score > ?', user.score]) + 1
```

Comment: Thanks Faisal, that was prefect.